# Mongo not starting on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongo on ubuntu using the instructions on the following page:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

```
deploy@stockgame-with-login:~$ mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.090 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=28452 port=27017 dbpath=/home/deploy/data/db 64-bit host=stockgame-with-login
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.091 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.14
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.092 [initandlisten] git version: 05bebf9ab15511a71bfbded684bb226014c0a553
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.092 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-154-253-119 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.092 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.093 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/home/deploy/data/db" }
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.098 [initandlisten] journal dir=/home/deploy/data/db/journal
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.099 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.209 [initandlisten] ****
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.210 [initandlisten] ****
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.210 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database local with pdfile version 4.22, new version: 4.5
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.210 [initandlisten]      Not upgrading, exiting
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.210 [initandlisten]      run --upgrade to upgrade dbs, then start again
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.210 [initandlisten] ****
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.210 dbexit: 
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.211 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.211 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.211 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.211 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.211 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.211 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.211 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.213 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.213 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.213 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.214 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
    Sun Jan 10 15:16:22.215 dbexit: really exiting now
    deploy@stockgame-with-login:~$
```

Comment: the link you posted is for installing on osx, but the title says you're running linux.  At first glance, i'd suggest taking a run at the [ubuntu version](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db --upgrade
```

The current database you are pointing appears to be from an older version of Mongo and it's format is deprecated.

Beware that this `--upgrade` argument will most likely not be backwards compatible, and older Mongo versions will not be able to read it. If that's not acceptable, you will need to open the database with an older version of Mongo such as 2.6.